# Crystal Report in c# window application

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, window, report

Here is my code to set data on my crystal report but data is not comin in data set but with the same time dataset is fill for datagridview. please help me. thanks in advance

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument crystalrpt = new ReportDocument();
        crystalrpt.Load(@"E:\c#\Date_day\Date_day\CR1.rpt");
        Rst_PrntDataSet prnt = Getdata("select * from dbo.EMPL_TRN");
        crystalrpt.SetDataSource(prnt);
        CRV1.ReportSource = crystalrpt;
        CRV1.Refresh();

    }

    private Rst_PrntDataSet Getdata(string qry)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Rst"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (Rst_PrntDataSet prnt = new Rst_PrntDataSet())
                {
                    da.Fill(prnt, "tbl1");
                    return prnt;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you change any db object after creating this report i.e. your report is upto date with database.

If yes, then please check in result in design mode by passing value (just F5 to view result).

If no, then simple go to "Database" menu -> "update database" and follow the step as below link

http://www.softwareforces.com/Support/Learning-Center/Step-by-Step/rpt-Inspector/Changing-Data-source-and-Database-Crystal-Reports-Dev-to-QA-to-Production

Comment: thanks for ur response sir, but m not changing any object and dataset contain data but not showing in details column only printing the headers

Comment: Hi , please check in design mode of crystal report that you get the result, then you check with your code. Becuase it is very simple query and seems report is also very simple. So you just check in result in designing mode by just pressing f5.